# Use value of Hyperlink column in a calculated column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column

I want to create a calculated column, it should show the value of Title and the URL of a Hyperlink column called Main Website. But I get an error for my formula:

```
=[Title]&" ("&[Main Website]&")"
```

If I replace [Main Website] with a reference to a Text column, the formula works ...

**Is there a way to use my URL in a calculated field?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in [SharePoint Columns – Features and limitations](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2011/07/sharepoint-columns-features-and-limitations) you'll see that you can't use Hyperlink columns in a calculated field.

Your options are to use an Event Receiver or a workflow update a text column with the coumputed value.

Comment: Thanks Per, I found a third way: using a standard text field and customizing the edit form via InfoPath, so the field is readonly and has a rule that concats Title and Hyperlink.